# SSRS Process data to get some percentages

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a database with some entries organized in categories and subcategories. I would like to create a report that shows how many entries are good/bad. I also need this report to be organised in categories that can be expandable to see subcategories result.

Here is a picture of what I need:

[image]

Can you help me with some suggestions about how can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two questions here.

**Percentage**

You can use an expression like the following to work this out:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!Flag.Value = "TRUE", 1, 0)) / CountRows()
```

i.e. the number of *TRUE* values in the group / total group rows.

**Drilldown**

You're looking for the [drilldown](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207042.aspx) functionality.

Consider a report like this:

[image]

You can set up drilldown with the **Row Visibility** for the bottom row:

[image]

Here *Category* is the name of the textbox to click to show/hide the row.

When the report is run you can click on the Category textbox to show or hide rows for that value.

Unexpanded:

[image]

Expanded:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
select category, subcategory, good/total *100, bad/total *100
from
    (select category, 
       subcategory,  
       sum(if (flag,1,0)) as good,
       sum(if (flag,0,1)) as bad,
       count(*) total
    from table_name
    group by category, subcategory)
```

Comment: The first table is already a processed dataset, it's not a table from a database. How can I do this query on it ?